# system error in loading json in background

Tags: java, android, json

I make an json loader class for load json objects from url . but when I run it its give some system error in logcat . but it do not force close application  . 
I dont know where is my mistake . and another question is that can  you show me some class that give it the json url and its get the jsons in  background and give the resualt ? 
tank you .
here is my code :

```
public class JSONLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
ProgressDialog dialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url = params[0];
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
        Log.d("result", page);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

}
```

}

error log :

```
  02-03 04:17:56.373: W/System.err(1592): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: (Forbidden)
02-03 04:17:56.383: W/System.err(1592):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
02-03 04:17:56.383: W/System.err(1592):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
02-03 04:17:56.393: W/System.err(1592):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
02-03 04:17:56.393: W/System.err(1592):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
02-03 04:17:56.403: W/System.err(1592):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
02-03 04:17:56.403: W/System.err(1592):     at plusnet.tashrifat.model.JSONLoader.doInBackground(JSONLoader.java:27)
02-03 04:17:56.403: W/System.err(1592):     at plusnet.tashrifat.model.JSONLoader.doInBackground(JSONLoader.java:1)
02-03 04:17:56.413: W/System.err(1592):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-03 04:17:56.413: W/System.err(1592):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-03 04:17:56.423: W/System.err(1592):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-03 04:17:56.433: W/System.err(1592):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-03 04:17:56.433: W/System.err(1592):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-03 04:17:56.433: W/System.err(1592):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Forbidden error occured in your server side you need configure access allow from all ip...

Comment: it seems that the URL requested is returning a 403 (Forbidden), can you verify that the url works in the browser?

Comment: yes the url working in browser .url : [link] (http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, from what you see here:

```
 02-03 04:17:56.373: W/System.err(1592): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: (Forbidden)
```

your server is returning a Forbidden response, check with your server admin what's the problem there, it's not in your code (unless you are missing some authentication or something like that)